# Searching within an Excel string

Tags: microsoft-excel, search

I have a column that contains a (varying amount) set of tags all comma separated. I'd like to convert some of these into a single column so I can separate items by the tags.

Sample cells:

```
* android,bug_report,cv_106213,server_api,unblock  
* android,cv_106213,inappropriate,server_api,video_report  
* not_bug_report  
* cv_2_2_0,false,feature_request,ios,server_api
* cv_2_0_2,ios,oldversion,server_api,true,video_report
```

I'd like to have a column that shows for each entry "android", "ios", or "other".  For the above samples I'd like to see:

```
* android
* android
* other
* ios
* ios
```

Comment: Can you ever have both android and ios in the string?  If so, how do you handle it?

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily handled by nesting a couple of `SEARCH` functions together.

[image: Androis search term]

The formula in B2 is,

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("android", A2)), "android", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ios", A2)), "ios", "other"))`

To make the search more precise (*ios* may be found within another word), bookend the text phrase with commas and search for *<comma><search term><comma>*.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",android,", ","&A2&",")), "android", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",ios,", ","&A2&",")), "ios", "other"))` 
The latter formula relies on you maintaining the comma separated format that seems to be prevalent in your sample data.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to note that `FIND` is case-sensitive while `SEARCH` is not.

Comment: Your answer is better.  I deleted mine.

Comment: Thanks.  I played with this direction but forgot to use ISNUMBER to turn the value into a bool so my IF failed the moment the substring wasn't at position 1.

Comment: Also, I'm thinking about a broader method to sort and count by the various tags.  Each week I have to build a report from ~5000 entries and show breakdown not only of platform but also bug/feature_request/question and also the specific bug types (cant_watch/no_notifications).  Any thoughts?

Comment: @SAR622 - Something of that scope would likely be better suited to a VBA based solution. Post another question showing sample data together with expected results and try to contribute some of your own effort whether it is working or not.